# Migration from 389 Directory Server to External OpenDJ

Tags: migration, openam, opendj, directory-server

Working with Community edition of OpenAM.

Currently, our datastore configured with 389 Directory Server contains the Configuration data of openAM.

Now, setup the datastore external OpenDJ but not able to migrate configuration data from 389 DS to external OpenDJ.

is any utility available to migrate the whole configuration to openDJ.

Need advice from experts.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The 'migration utility' would be LDIF. You could perform an ldif export on 389 Directory Server and perform ldif import on OpenDJ but I wonder why you would quit using 389 DS. In last community edition, OpenAM does not use any OpenDJ specific features and OpenDJ replication works totally different as the one from 389 DS (which originated from Netscape DS).

Comment: Yup tried with export and import but in it, some of attributes will not map due to receiving the error.

As currently, we are running OpenAM 12 now want to deploy 14.4 version for that we have to setup now external OpenDJ

Comment: OpenAM 14.4. is not open-source ... where does it come from? It might not even be 'OpenAM'. Attribute will always 'map', but of course you have to update the schema (the collection of attributeTypes and objectclasses).

Comment: Yeah, update schema for it setup 12.x with OpenAM and exported 99-user.ldif under config/schema and then try to import and succeed.